# Displaying a specific view in browser. Mistake in routes.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, controller

Im trying to display a simple starting view in my browser by doing `http://localhost:3000/project/claim` but it keeps giving:

`No route matches [GET] "/project/claim"`

**`routes.rb`** file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
........
get 'project/claim' => 'claim#index'
```

**`controller/claim_controller`** file:

```
class ClaimController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @message = "Hello, World!"
    end
end
```

**`/views/claim/claim.html.erb`** file:

```
<h1>A greeting for you! </h1>

<p> <%= @message %>  </p>
```

Comment: Just tested it, it should work with your code. Perhaps you could share your repo so I can test it here... It's pretty de-motivating to try and help while getting downvoted though...

Comment: Could you run `rake routes` and post the output here?

Comment: I think your problem could be that you are not following rest.  The claims index should be /claims.  /claim should be the show page for claim not the index.

Comment: @ruby_newbie, what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: Rails follows restful routing.  If you don't name stuff correctly it gets confused.  get 'project/claim' => 'claim#index'   should be get 'project/claims' => 'claim#index'  according to restful routing.  This file "/views/claim/claim.html.erb "   should be called /views/claim/claims.html.erb according to restful routing best practices.  When you name it how you have, rails thinks that you are referring to the   show action because that is what convention is.  That said you should still post the output of rake routes as suggested by nicholas.

Comment: this isn't true, you can name your routes whatever you want. RESTful style is just the default with scaffolds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rename:
`/views/claim/claim.html.erb`
on
`/views/claim/index.html.erb`

Comment: @user6465508 because the route looks into `claim#index` and to `calm#calm` ;)